# Table not creating on android device but creating on the virtual device

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio

So I am trying to create a Database and a table in android studio. The database is created successfully but table is not creating when I am using my android phone but both the database and the table are created when I use Virtual device from the AVD.

```
public class Databases extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static  final String dbname = "AttendanceDb11";

    public Databases(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, dbname, null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE Student12 ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name Text)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        db.execSQL("Drop table if exists Student12");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Here is my code

Comment: can you share the crash log?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` .Kindly share logcat please

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that app was already installed before you created the tables. I would do one of the following:

1: Uninstalling and re-installing the app.

2: The best and better approach is to drop and recreate table in onUpdate method, and increase the db version whenever you change the schema.